# Adding 301 permanent redirections in Craft CMS

Tags: craft3

I am not able to redirect any dead page. Although I have added the redirection but it is not getting reflected. Please help.

Comment: How did you add the redirection? Please leave more details.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you're trying to do the redirect, but the common ways in Craft are:

1) From .htaccess if you're using Apache: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

2) Using a plugin that lets you set up redirects from the Craft control panel: https://plugins.craftcms.com/search?q=redirect